# Catch Block is Fired When There is No Exception to Catch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, try-catch, redux-actions

I am following a tutorial, but I am not sure why my catch block is catching anything as there is no exception thrown. The result is `undefined` with no error.

The `history.pushState()` doesn't get called at all. After the `axios.post()` command is fired, it just goes to the catch block. I know the `axios.post()` command is working properly because the project object is saved in the database and no error is thrown in the backend.

Here is the action:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GET_ERRORS } from "./types";

export const createProject = (project, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/project", project);
    history.pushState("/dashboard");
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: err.response.data,
    });
  }
};
```

This the error I get:

```
projectActions.js:15 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
at projectActions.js:15
```

Comment: Is there some activity in the network tab in browser's dev tools to see? You want to look for status code and response data.

Comment: So the axios request is returning with an error status code, some 4XX or 5XX one. That's why it falls into the error block. And then the error message likely due to the payload of ur dispatch, basically `err.response` is undefined, so trying to access the `data` property of it is throwing that error. Look in the network tab to see the statuses response status, and print out the returned error stuff in the catch block to see what's happening

Comment: I printed out the error. The error being thrown is `err: TypeError: history.pushState is not a function`. So, I guess the error isn't coming from the response.

Comment: You can print the history object to see what it is